# SharePoint 2010 Connect to Oracle Databases

Tags: sharepoint-2010, oracle11g, bcs

I'm looking to retrieve data from Oracle Databases, take the queried information and place it into SharePoint 2010.  Is there a way to achieve this without the help of BCS metaman?  All the tutorials I've come across seem to reference this software.  BCS metaman isn't an option in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [MSDN Article - How to: Connect to an Oracle Database Using Business Connectivity Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464424%28office.14%29.aspx) and this [SharePoint Journal blog post - Business Connectivity Services (BCS) with Oracle using Visual Studio 2010](http://sharepointjournals.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/business-connectivity-services-bcs-with-oracle-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1/)